# Unable to get response from end url using XMLHTTP GET request in Excel VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to retrieve a table from web using excel vba xmlhttp GET method.
When I send the end url(ie `Url_Sub2`), after sending the referrer url(ie `Url_Main`), an error output is displayed HTTP Status 405. Kindly help.

```
Option Explicit
Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60,html As New HTMLDocument
Dim sResp$, Url_Main$, Url_Sub1$, Url_Sub2$


Sub FetchHistoricalDataWorking()
    
    'URL
        Url_Main$ = "https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm"
        
        Url_Sub1$ = "https://www1.nseindia.com/marketinfo/sym_map/symbolCount.jsp?symbol=LUPIN"
        Url_Sub2$ = "https://www1.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?symbol=LUPIN&segmentLink=3&symbolCount=2&series=ALL&dateRange=3month&fromDate=&toDate=&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE"
      
    'XML Link
        With xmlhttp
            .Open "GET", Url_Main$, False '/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm"
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
            .setRequestHeader "Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
            .setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"
            .setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-IN,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
            .setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
            .setRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
            .setRequestHeader "Host", "www1.nseindia.com"
            .send
            While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            
            .Open "GET", Url_Sub1$, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
            .setRequestHeader "Referer", Url_Main$
            .setRequestHeader "Accept", "*/*"
            .setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"
            .setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-IN,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
            .setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
            .setRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
            .setRequestHeader "Host", "www1.nseindia.com"
            .send
            While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            
            .Open "GET", Url_Sub2$, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
            .setRequestHeader "Referer", Url_Main$
            .setRequestHeader "Accept", "*/*"
            .setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"
            .setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-IN,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
            .setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
            .setRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
            .setRequestHeader "Host", "www1.nseindia.com"
            .send
            While .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            
            sResp = .responseText
            Debug.Print sResp
        End With

        html.body.innerHTML = sResp
    '       Debug.Print oHttp.readyState & oHttp.Status
         
End Sub
```

[image: Output required table]
[image: Initiator from network tools]
[image: Getting response from URLUrl_Sub1]
[image: HTTP Status error 405 XMLHTTP GET request for Url_Sub2]
[image: Network tools]

Comment: Isn't it shown at the bottom of the request chain shown above?

Comment: yes, how do I retrieve the table? I cannot send "GET" `Url_Sub1` directly after sending `Url_Main`. I'm missing a middle step of JavaScript sending queries after which it leads to `Url_Sub1` where the info is stored. The info table is attachment image1 @QHarr

Comment: Why can you not send GET directly to the end url in the chain? Did you try?

Comment: I have tried sending end url `Url_Sub1` directly, but it returns error: HTTP Status 405 ? Method Not Allowed
Type Status Report

Message Access denied

Description The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource. @QHarr

Comment: https://www1.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?symbol=lupin&segmentLink=3&symbolCount=2&series=ALL&dateRange=3month&fromDate=&toDate=&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE

Comment: How do I workaround this HTTP error 405? I'm missing some middle step which is not allowing end url to respond. But this url responds if i manually formfill by visting Main url and submit.  @QHarr